# Creating encrypted Zip files that are compatible with the TrueZip Java Library (Winzip AES?)

Tags: java, encryption, truezip

Is try to create an encrypted ZIP file which is compatible with the TrueZIP java library.

I tried `7z`

```
7za -tzip -mem=AES256 a out.myzip -pFoo in.file
```

but when decrypting in TrueZIP I get the exception:

```
W/System.err: de.schlichtherle.truezip.io.InputException:   
 java.util.zip.ZipException: in.file (encrypted compression method 8 
 is not supported)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using

```
 7z -tzip -mm=Deflate -mem=AES256 a ....
```

and

```
    @Override
    public AesKeyStrength getKeyStrength(String arg0)
            throws ZipKeyException {
        return AesKeyStrength.BITS_256;
    }
```

on the Java side.